# How do I move two tiled modal forms together?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two modal userforms, frmA and frmB.  I would like to tile the forms and when I move the top form, I would like the other form to follow it, remaining in a tiled position as if they are tied together.

FrmA has a button to Open frmB.
When frmB opens, it is active and the user interacts with it, while frmA is visible but cannot be moved or accessed by the user. That is all expected.

```
'This is part of the frmA command button to open frmB
'Load, Initialize and Show form B. Send coordinates of form A
        Set formB = New frmB
        Load formB
        Dim iA_Left As Integer
        Dim iA_Top As Integer
        iA_Left = Me.Left
        iA_Top = Me.Top
        ' Initialize formB and pass current position of formA byRef (used by activate event)
        If Not formB.bInitialize(vbFalse, , , iA_Top, iA_Left) Then Err.Raise glHANDLED_ERROR
        If iA_Top <> -1 Then
            miA_Top = iA_Top
        End If
        If iA_Left <> -1 Then
            miA_Left = iA_Left
        End If
        formB.Show
```

I have figured out how to use the userform Activate event to tile frmB over frmA (a little down and to the right). Then when frmB closes, I pass back frmA's original left and top so that after it reinitializes, it will appear in its original position.

```
' This is from frmB Activate event
' The variables miA_Left and miA_Top are set in Initialize event via optional variables
'   passed from the code above.
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
        If miA_Left <> -1 Then
            Me.Left = miA_Left + 15
        End If
        If miA_Top <> -1 Then
            Me.Top = miA_Top + 15
        Else
            Me.Top = Round((Application.Top + Application.Height) / 2 - Me.Height / 2, 0)
        End If
End Sub


' This is from frmB Layout Event
Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
    Debug.Print "Layout Left " & Me.Left
    If miA_Left <> -1 And miA_Top <> -1 Then ' In this case, it's true and proceeds to next line
        frmA.Left = Me.Left - 10
        frmA.Top = Me.Top - 10
    End If
End Sub
```

When I debug the Layout event, before the first assignment I put my cursor over frmA.Top and it says "object variable not set" but then it proceeds to assign the number to frmA.Left without error.  However, it does not change the position of frmA.  The name of the form class is actually frmA, but when I created a variable to generate the form, I used

```
Dim formA as frmA
Set formA = New frmA
```

However, formA would not be in the scope of frmB, so I don't think I can reference that variable.

What I need to do is when the user drags frmB around, I want frmA to follow it, remaining tiled.  I cannot figure out how to change .Top and .Left of frmA while frmB is active.  I have tried various statements in the Activate and Layout events of frmB, but am not sure how to access frmA directly from frmB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Layout` event of form B to change the position of form A.

Something like (assuming form A is called `frmA`)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
    frmA.Top = Me.Top - 15
    frmA.Left = Me.Left - 15

End Sub
```

---

**Update**  'Normal' use of forms

As you hinted at in your comment, using instances of forms is usefull when you want to show more than one instance.  The 'normal' method is to just refer to the base form class names themselves.
Eg If we have two forms: `frmA` and `frmB`, with `frmA` containing a command button and `frmB` containing no controls, we can demo the tiling code as follows (code below is the entire content of the modules mentioned)

```
' Code in a standard Module, to show frmA
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    frmA.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

.

```
' Code in frmA
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    frmB.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

.

```
' Code in frmB
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    frmB.Top = Me.Top + 15
    frmB.Left = Me.Left + 15
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
    frmA.Top = Me.Top - 15
    frmA.Left = Me.Left - 15
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried exactly this but it did not change the position of frmA at all.

Comment: I tried it before posting, and it does work for me.  Maybe there is more to your code than you have posted...

Comment: I added some details to my question about how I declared variables. Maybe I am referencing it wrong. Please see main question.

Comment: Do you think I need to make formA global in order to make this work, instead of referencing frmA object?

Comment: OK, I see what happening.  You are creating an _instance_ of `frmA` and showing that (called `formA`).  the code `frmA.Top.`... does not reference that instance.  Before I dig into how to get around that, satisfy my curiosity: what's the reason for showing instances of the forms, and not just frmA and frmB directly?

Comment: simultanious typing... Yep, creating `formA` as a global would work, but it kind of defeats the purpose of creating instances.  I'd still like tp know why you are using them at all.

Comment: When I created formA as a global, it worked. I am using instances because I don't know any better.  I often create an instance and reinitialize it after the user makes changes that are saved to the worksheet, then redisplay it.  I never need to show more than one instance of a form. If you can point me to more info about using the form and not an instance, that would be great.  It may simplify things. I am already 10000 LOC deep in this, but willing to learn. Some of the things I did first are the things I did worst.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This means I can get rid of all that variable passing and setting I was doing in my original solution. Bonus.